# AMP-HTML mail - how to communicate with the server and fetch json?

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

Is it possible using AMP-HTML mail format to communicate with the server? I don't think it's documented that well. There is some info about normal AMP-HTML but not much about email.

This is amp mail I want to send. I would like secret word to be fetched from my server and not hardcoded.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Store complex nested JSON data in <amp-state> elements. -->
    <amp-state id="words">
      <script type="application/json">
        {
          "SecretWord": "fetched"
        }
      </script>
    </amp-state>

    <p [text]="'Your word is: ' + currentWord + '.'">Click to show magic word</p>


    <button on="tap:AMP.setState({currentWord: words['SecretWord']})">Show word</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no much documentation about AMP4Email. Recently, with a lot of unsuccessful efforts, I've managed to complete one of my use-case using AMP4Email.

You can refer to the below example for achieving your goal:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <amp-state id="fruits"
    src="https://amp.dev/static/samples/json/related_products.json"></amp-state>

    <p [text]="'My favorite fruit is : ' + favoriteFruit + '.'">Click to find my favorite fruit.</p>

    <button on="tap:AMP.setState({favoriteFruit: fruits.items[0]['name']})">Show</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have used an API from an example by `ampproject.org`, which returns a JSON of `items` of fruits. But, you can write your own API that sends your favorite word only.

In order to write your own service, you have to be very careful with the response headers. If you look for the response headers of this API, you'll see some headers like `access-...` and `amp-...`. These headers are mandatory if you want to use your API/ service in AMP4Email.

The mandatory Response Headers are:

```
AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: <value received in __amp_source_origin query param for your service>
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin, e.g. 'https://mail.google.com', if your service is hit from GMail inbox)
```

PS: `__amp_source_origin` header is appended by GMail. You will receive this header for all the requests coming from AMP4Email HTML.